# WM_Quit message being sent when i click on textbox

Tags: c++, c, winapi

so title says it all. i was thinking maybe because there are 81 textboxes it has somthing to do with layers but quite frankly i have no idea.. just started learning windows api like 2 days ago and ive been learning streight off the msdn library for functions.. i googled this problem multiple times and no luck so here i am. the help is much appreciated ^.^

```
// Win32Project9.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32Project9.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

HWND Hwnd;
HMENU hMenu;
HWND boxes[81];
int x, y;
vector<LPWSTR> BoxNum;


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(msg)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDM_EXIT:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    break;

    case ID_SOLVE:
        for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
        {
            GetWindowText(boxes[i], BoxNum[i], NULL);
        }
    break;
    }
break;
}

if (msg == WM_COMMAND)
{
    if (LOWORD(wParam) > 199 && LOWORD(wParam) < 281)
    {
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_SETFOCUS | HIWORD(wParam) == EN_UPDATE)
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}

else if (msg == WM_CLOSE)
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
}

return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void DrawBoard()
{
x = 10;
y = 10;
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
{
    int BOX_ID = 200 + i;
    boxes[i] = CreateWindow(TEXT("Edit"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, 20, 20, Hwnd, (HMENU)BOX_ID, NULL, NULL);

    x += 30;
    count++;

    if (count == 9)
    {
        y += 30;
        x = 10;
        count = 0;
    }
}
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine,
               int nCmdShow)
{   

//structure to hold window specs
WNDCLASSEX Wc;

//allocate memory for window class
ZeroMemory(&Wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

//fill in neccessary info
Wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

Wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
Wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
Wc.hInstance = hInstance;
Wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
Wc.lpszClassName = L"MyClass";
Wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

//register class
RegisterClassEx(&Wc);

//load menu into handle
hMenu = LoadMenu(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_MENU));

//Create Window with class and create handle
Hwnd = CreateWindow(L"MyClass", L"Sudoku", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 300, 340, NULL, hMenu, hInstance, NULL);

//DisplayWindow
ShowWindow(Hwnd, nCmdShow); 

DrawBoard();

//structure to hold input stream
MSG msg;

//listen for input
while(GetMessage(&msg, Hwnd, NULL, NULL))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return 0;
}
```

also i read that wm_close is processed when i press the x button. well this message is being recieved even when i click the text boxes. and if you look at my case WM_Close.. i coded it to make a message box and give the user a chance to accept or not.... so when this happens after clicking on a text box i click no and another message box apperas asking again, i click no and it goes away but when i click the x button and i click no the window still dissapears .....

Comment: Have you determined that you are actually getting `WM_QUIT` vs. simply crashing (and if so, how)?

Comment: yes ive realized im getting this message i just cant explain why

Comment: All of your text boxes have the same control id. Not really a good idea.

Comment: maybe i misunderstand but they are all in an array. each time it creates a new textbox it puts it in the next position in the array.. as in boxes[0], boxes[1], boxes[2], etc. did you miss that or am i misunderstanding? im not arguing with you, just clarifying

Comment: The `hMenu` argument passed to [`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx) specifies the child window identifier. That's how you distinguish them when processing messages like `WM_COMMAND` and notifications.

Comment: so how would i implement this?? i dont really understand because my goal was for the user to click solve under file using ID_SOLVE which will then use GetWindowText from each boxes[i] and store it somewhere else so i feel theres no need to access it through wm_command unless your saying the window doesnt know what to do with the text boxes BECAUSE im not accessing it through wm command

Comment: Edit controls also send WM_COMMAND messages to tell you what's going on with them.  Like EN_SELCHANGE.  Or EN_SETFOCUS when you click on them.  Wrapped in a WM_COMMAND message that's sent to their own window.  You must pay attention to where the message came from, LPARAM argument.

Comment: No need to use a large `switch` statement. After you update your code to assign identifiers to the textboxes take the value of `id = LOWORD(lParam)`, validate it's in range of the text boxes, adjust it accordingly (`id - FirstControlId`), and use that as an index into your array or vector.

Comment: *PROBLEM SOLVED AND CODE UPDATED*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably that `WM_COMMAND` is not handled properly.

The arguments received are as follows:

```
WORD code = HIWORD(wParam);
WORD id = LOWORD(lParam);
```

The problem is that `code` depends on the type of control you are using. For example, if it is a button it will be some of the `BTN_*` values, if it is an edit it will be `EN_*` and so on. But these values overlap badly, so you cannot use them in a single switch.

For example `CBN_KILLFOCUS==4`, but also `LBN_SETFOCUS==4`... Also menu items will get here a 0 and accelerators a 1. By the way, `BN_CLICKED==0` and it looks like no other notification message uses 0, so you can use the same IDs in menus and buttons and it will just work. And accelerators too, with a bit of care... `BN_PAINT==1`, I think this one does not exist anymore, but you get the point...

Anyway, to your problem. My guess is that you have an EDIT that happens to have an ID equal to `IDM_EXIT`. Since you are not checking the `HIWORD(wParam)` you are quitting when you receive the `EN_SETFOCUS` on this control.

The solution is: First, always check both WORDs from `wParam`. Second, avoid collisions between menu options and ID controls, except maybe with buttons.

Answer (score 4):

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
```

That isn't quite good enough.  Edit controls also send WM_COMMAND messages to notify their parent window about stuff going on.  Like EN_UPDATE whenever you type a character.  Or [EN_SETFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761685%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when they get the focus, sounds like your case when you see this go wrong when you click on them.  These notifications are wrapped in a WM_COMMAND message.

You must therefore pay attention to where the WM_COMMAND message came from.  The LPARAM argument tells you.  If IDM_EXIT comes from a menu item then you *must* verify that LPARAM is 0.  Check the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: ahhhh ok thank you very much. id give you a point but i dont have enough rep >.< lol